# change your location to the fake location

Tags: android, location

I want to change my location in my device. my location is already shown the right one, but I just want to use fake location Instead of the right one. now my location is Tehran , how to change my location to the Turkey?

here is my code:

```
public class main extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    public LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
        mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
        btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.set);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Location location = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
                location.setLatitude(32.87972);
                location.setLongitude(39.967203);
                location.setAltitude(0);
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, location);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" Longitude: "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Change location in DEVICE or in app??

Comment: i want to change my location in DEVICE

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using apps like FakeGPS. You will need to enable "Allow Mock Locations" in developer settings.

Comment: I know that , it is ebable.

Comment: no, i easily get the fake location , although allow mock location is on but it doesn't change anything

Comment: why do you have location hard-coded in the code snippet you posted? is that the reason you are getting same location?

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you mean, you can use the *"Allow Mock Locations"* like notsopopularguy said. Make sure you have **developer settings** turned on.

If you what to change it in app just change the below code with new values.

```
location.setLatitude(32.87972);
location.setLongitude(39.967203);
```

Turkeys Latitude and longitude are as follows 38.963745 & 35.243322. Insert these into the required places above.